# "Мы (—) то, что мы едим": нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

По идее, в этой фразе пропущено "это", и тире нужно ставить. Но, может, я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тире здесь не нужно. Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если они выражены существительными (Земля - планета), числительными (дважды два - четыре), инфинитивами (курить - здоровью вредить).  Если подлежащее выражено местоимением, то тире не ставится. Разве что интонационное. Но здесь и оно не нужно. Здесь логическое ударение на  сказуемом "то".

Answer (score 2):

"Это" здесь не пропущено. Если что и пропущено, то "есть", глагол-связка. 
Касательно тире. Оно возможно, но не обязательно, в зависимости от интонации и/или смыслового акцента. В нейтральной фразе я бы не ставил.

Answer (score 0):

По моему мнению, речеподражательный сигнал "Мы - то, что мы едим." аналогичен сигналам "Мы были то, что мы ели." и "Мы будем то, что мы будем есть".

P.S. Сравните сигнал "Мы - то, что мы едим." с предложением "Мы - млекопитающие." и предложением "For all we have and are, for all our children's fate, stand up and take the war: the Hun is at the gate.".